# Generate ImapMessage from Response Object

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I've created a custom command to retrieve multiple objects in the same request (in order to solve some performance issues), instead of using the folder method `.getMessage(..)` which in my case retrieved an `ImapMessage` object:

```
    Argument args = new Argument();
    args.writeString(Integer.toString(start) + ":" + Integer.toString(end));
    args.writeString("BODY[]");

    FetchResponse fetch;
    BODY body;
    MimeMessage mm;
    ByteArrayInputStream is = null;
    Response[] r = protocol.command("FETCH", args);
    Response status = r[r.length-1];
    if(status.isOK()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < r.length - 1; i++) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Currently I'm validating if the object is a `ImapResponse` like this:

```
    if (r[i] instanceof IMAPResponse) {
       IMAPResponse imr = (IMAPResponse)r[i];
```

My question is, how can I turn this response into an `ImapMessage`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't succeeded yet to convert it into a IMAPMessage but I'm now able transform it into a MIME Message. It isn't perfect but I guess it will have to work for now:

```
FetchResponse fetch = (FetchResponse) r[i];
BODY body = (BODY) fetch.getItem(0);
ByteArrayInputStream is = body.getByteArrayInputStream();
MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session, is);
```

Then, it can be used to get information like this:

```
String contentType = mm.getContentType();
Object contentObject = mm.getContent();
```

There are also other methods to get information like the sender, date, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to download the entire message content for multiple messages at once?  Have you tried using [IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.MESSAGE](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.html#MESSAGE)?  That will cause Folder.fetch to download the entire message content, which you can then access using the Message objects.

Comment: From what I understand, the fetch requires that I've already downloaded the messages information as one of the parameters is a message array. I want to list & bring all the messages in just one call. The custom command I've created does that but I can't find a way to convert it to an IMAPMessage. Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstand.  The getMessage methods that return Message objects don't download anything at all.  They just return local Messages objects that are a proxy for the information available on the server.  When you call one of the methods on the Message object, it fetches the information from the server if it doesn't have it already.  By using the fetch method, JavaMail prefetches the information so that it's available when you call the method on the Message object.